# Cover polygon with minimal number of overlapping polygons at fixed positions

Tags: polygon, geospatial, computational-geometry, combinatorics

How to select the minimal number of polygons from a set of polygons with fixed positions, whose union covers the input polygon?

For example, let's consider the following input, where the green polygons are the queried set and the blue one is the query:

[image: Input and Query]

The correct covering would be with two polygons:

[image: Expected Result]

How to calculate which polygons most efficiently cover the input area (minimizing the number of selected polygons)?

Comment: Do you also want to minimize the returned area? In your example, the left neighbor instead of your chosen left polygon would also cover the input area. But the result would be larger. How is this question geo-related?

Comment: The geospatial application is to select the smallest number of aerial photos that cover a requested area (the vendor of geospatial data might charge per photo). The total area of the selected polygons is not important in this case, only the number of polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seems to give correct results is the following:

1. Clip all polygons to the queried area
2. Divide each of the clipped polygon with any others that intersect it, eliminating any duplicates - let's call this operation "chopping". For example, such operation would produce the following non-overlapping polygons:

[image]

From the following polygons (clipped by range):

[image]

3. All of the chopped polygons represent the universe in the set covering terms; the chopped polygons covered by a single clipped cover polygon represent a subset
4. Pre-select all subsets corresponding to the polygons that are not fully covered by the union of other polygons.
5. Use the approximate algorithm to find the minimum set cover (as described [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-cover-problem-set-1-greedy-approximate-algorithm/))

I've implemented this using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/). Here's the code: https://github.com/w-k/MinimalCoverage and the archive with the jar and the dependencies can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/w-k/MinimalCoverage/releases.

---

I've based this on Ante's answer which was very valuable but did not provide the correct solution. It is incorrect because satisfying the requirement that all intersection parts be covered, results in excessive coverage of the query polygon. For example, the cover polygons clipped by the range polygon (as in the picture above) produce the following common parts:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In order to cover all of the common parts we would have to select all three cover polygons (the middle common part is not entirely covered by either the leftmost nor the rightmost polygon).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that polygons are quads, and that you want to maximize returned area for minimal number of photos since with that you will obtain more area for same cost which can be used in future.

This is just a thought about solution.

For each polygon intersection part store list of cover polygons that contain that intersection part. In your example, there are ~30 intersection parts. Some of them are quads, some are L shaped.

For query polygon find all intersection parts that polygon contains or intersects. With that we have set of intersection parts and for each part list of cover polygons. Like:

```
ip_1 - [c1, c3]
ip_2 - [c1, c2, c3, c6]
...
```

Inverting this 'matrix':

```
c1 - [ip_1, ip_2, ...]
c2 - [ip_2, ... ]
c3 - [ip_1, ip_2, ... ]
```

Finding minimal number of `c's` that union of lists is whole set of `ip's` is [set covering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

This method finds optimal solution. It works with general polygons. In simplest version it doesn't solve area maximization.

Problem is in implementation :-)

First is creation of data structure that support indexing by polygons. For that some space partition structure is needed. Inserting new polygon into data structure means creation of new intersections with intersection parts already in structure. I think that number of intersection parts at the end will be constant factor to number of cover polygons. If you have quads regularly spaced, than cover consists of `n*m` parts, where `n` and `m` are probably small.

Second is set cover problem, it is NP-complete. I hope that you will have not too much of sets to cover.